# Makefile in sub-directory

Tags: c++, makefile

I am trying to write a makefile in a subdirectory of my eclipse makefile project.

```
MyProject \
  test.cpp
  Build\
    Makefile
```

I am also trying to create a generic makefile.  I am having trouble defining the targets since the build is not happening in the same directory as the source.

```
CC = g++
CC_FLAGS = -g3

EXEC = test
SOURCEDIR = ..
SOURCES = $(shell find $(SOURCEDIR) -name '*.c' -o -name '*.cpp')
OBJECTS = $(addsuffix .o,$(subst ../,,$(SOURCES)))

.DEFAULT_GOAL = all

$(EXEC): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $(EXEC)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CC_FLAGS) $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(EXEC) $(OBJECTS)

.PHONY: all 
all: $(EXEC)
```

Right now when I build I get the error...

```
make all 
make: *** No rule to make target 'test.cpp.o', needed by 'test'.  Stop.
```

Can anyone tell me why this is not working or recommend a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your dependency from object to source as follows:

```
 %.cpp.o: $(SOURCEDIR)/%.cpp
```

it seems to work.

In general I would prefer to NOT do anything in a build dir, because I personally expect a build dir is a temporary dir which can be removed completely for distribution which is not the case if the Makefile resists there. But this is a matter of taste.

Also I do not prefer to use all c/cpp you find as objects/sources in the make process. If you need to add files for different variants in your projects, you enter a nightmare to change all these things later.

And also as a hint: Typically objects are `<basename>.o` and not `<basename>.cpp.o`

And another one:
Users expect that the `clean` target also remove the executable. If not, you will never see a rebuild by simply do `make clean; make`, because the executable is in place and all dependencies are fulfilled.